# C# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() hangs when requesting a method of Azure web role

Tags: c#, azure, httprequest, freeze

I'm writing code to send a request to my web service in windows azure, and it turned out I cannot get response until timeout. What's confusing is that i'm sure everything inside my service has been done, and yet the response did not come back.

My service code looks like this:

```
public virtual JsonResult ServiceMethod()
{
    // 1. do the work
    // 2. write something to database

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And my client code looks like this:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(httpAddress)) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Timeout = 1000 * 1000;
webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 40 * 60 * 1000;
webRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 40 * 60 * 1000;
webRequest.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 50 * 1000, 1000);
webRequest.Method = "GET";


using (HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    // handle the response
}
```

Now I'm pretty sure my code in my service has completed because i tried to write something to database and that happened. I also checked the iis log on the virtual machine where the service is hosted and it showed http 200 is returned. But the call GetResponse() in my client code hanged until the 1000 seconds timeout is reached.

### Update

There is a parameter to my web API which will affect how long the method runs.(I didn't show it in the above code for simplicity). If the service method runs for sufficiently long time (like 6 or 7 minutes), then the hanging problem will happen. Otherwise, the web response can successfully return. So i guess there might be some problem within the timeout setting. But there are several timeout properties in the HttpWebRequest and its base classes, i don't know what combination of them can result in or solve this problem.

Any ideas of what can the problem be?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any luck resolving this?

Comment: @StijnDeVos unfortunately no...this was a test project and somehow we didnt need it, so the problem was never resolved

Comment: Too bad. I 'solved' this by implementing a custom polling mechanism (web call starts a remote action, catch possible timeout exception, poll status until done)

Answer (score 0):

From your code, and since you're returning `JsonResult` from your action, it seems that you have a RESTful architecture. One of the ways to debug RESTful architectures is to use browser, specifically in your case where HTTP method is **GET**.

You can simply copy/paste your URL in the address bar of a browser to see if you get any response. If you see the result, then your client code is the problem, otherwise, the problem is in the server side (azure server).

To monitor HTTP traffic, a good utility is [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It is a restful architecture and i did try the api in browser (actually using chrome plugin postman), the result is i did not get response there either. Also, i realized i missed one important thing in the original question. I've mentioned it in the update section, could you see if that can help trouble shooting? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run your project locally in the Windows Azure emulator. Then, check the output of the compute emulator. It should show unhandled exceptions there.

It seems that the call to your external service fails, and the exception is not handled properly. We've had a similar case before, and it would even cause the IIS worker process to crash.